# I have to change the array index for the cookie to work

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, cookies

i have a problem here with cookie in js .
the work of page is : let the user to choose one of background colors and this color will store in cookie , i wrote the codes and the cookie was working and i put expires date in 2023 and the date is correct , but when i close it and try to open the page in the next day i saw the cookie was not working , so when i try to fix the problem i try to change the number of array although i know it is not the solution but when i do it , the cookie worked although the index of array is not correct so i left it in the wrong index and i tried to open it in the next day to see if every thing is right or not but the same problem happen the cookie wasn't working so i know the problem is from the index i changed the index to the correct one and i worked , and everyday i suffer of this problem , so can any one explain that and tell me the problem ? (i left some comments with the codes).

thank you

```
    HTML Codes:

    <ul>
    <li id="red" onclick="color(this.id);"></li>    
    <li id="blue" onclick="color(this.id);"></li>    
    <li id="green" onclick="color(this.id);"></li>    
    <li id="white" onclick="color(this.id);"></li>    
    <li id="black" onclick="color(this.id);"></li>    
    <li id="pink" onclick="color(this.id);"></li>    
    <li id="close">X</li>    

    </ul>




    JS codes :
    <script>

    function color(id)
    {
    document.bgColor=id;
    document.cookie="color="+id+";expires=Sun, 27 Aug 2023 10:00:00 UTC;path=/";
    /*stored the color and the expires date */ 
    }

    window.onload=function()
    {
    if (document.cookie.length != 0)
    {
    var sp = document.cookie.split("="); 
     document.bgColor=sp[1]; /* here I have to change the number of index everyday to let the 
     cookie works and i don't know why */ 
     }

    else
    {
    alert('cookie not found');
    }


    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Are there other cookies?

Comment: no , only this  cookie